# Is it possible to add a separator in TextMate's function popup?

Tags: textmate, textmate2

Is it possible to add one or more separators to the function popup in TextMate 2? Some context may help understand what I mean:

[image: TextMate 2 function popup]

I'd like to group the functions into logical sections, similar to what Xcode does with the '#pragma -' option. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: This is probably more of a question for the textmate support page (very responsive) or apple.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested with TextMate version 2.0-alpha.9479 and

```
#pragma mark -
```

worked fine in a .cpp file.

It's a per-bundle trick and the Javascript bundle doesn't have it.
You can do it yourself by customizing the bundle to recognize some specially formatted comments for instance.

Comment: `#pragma mark - blah blah` is fairly widely supported for .c, .cpp, .h and .m files.  Do you have a solution that works with .php?  Thanks!

Comment: @Olie Same idea: look at how it is done in the C/C++ bundle and hack something similar in the PHP bundle.